Automating F-Curve changes in Blender/Python to Match Song
I have a visualizer in Blender that can visualize songs. While I can change the songs using a script, I'm struggling to adjust the visualizer's f-curves to match the dynamics of the new songs. This process is being handled headlessly on a console with the following command:
blender -b "path\blender.blend" -P "path\python.py"

In the script, I successfully change the song in the video sequencer and render the final output. However, I'm unable to figure out how to modify the f-curves accordingly. How can I programmatically adjust the f-curves in Blender to the new song?

I found a way to do this with bpy.ops.graph.sound_to_samples.
If bpy.ops.graph.sound_to_samples is used and not some calculation on our own we need to do some steps.
First go into the Blender file add a Keyframe to an Object or Geometry Node, also insert a song.
Next we go into the editor we need the Context we get it like this.
def get_context(type):
    for screen in bpy.data.screens:
        for area in screen.areas:
            if area.type == type:
                context_override = {"area": area, "screen": screen}
                return context_override

After that we set the Context in temp_override.
Its important to set the active Object, in my case Cube.
If its a Geometry Node use the Parent Object.
def sound_to_sample(context, mp3):
    override = get_context("GRAPH_EDITOR")

    with context.temp_override(**override):
        obj = bpy.data.objects.get("Cube")
        context.view_layer.objects.active = obj
        obj.select_set(True)
        bpy.ops.graph.sound_to_samples(filepath=mp3) #important this changes the curves

so now we can just use
sound_to_sample(bpy.context, mp3FilePath)

